# Entity Framework - change connectionstring has error with sqlite

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, connection-string

My original connection string:

```
<add name="mainEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;
                 provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6;
                 provider connection string='data source=&quot;
  C:\Users\Nam\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Product.db&quot;'" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

My new connection string (I edited my old connection string):

```
<add name="mainEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;
         provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6;
         provider connection string='data source=&quot;|DataDirectory|Product.db&quot;'" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

And my code in my winform is:

```
 var db = new mainEntities();

 if (db.FCUsers.Count() == 1) 
      MessageBox.Show("ok");
```

When I debug my project It was like:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnzj5.png)

I saw the way is put file.db into file debug. I has to do this But it still doesn't work. Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: check this link [link]https://medium.com/@alexandermlharris/sqlite-and-ef6-the-tutorial-that-works-181da420899f

Comment: @JeePakaJP thanks. it still doesn't work.... :((

Comment: show me your app.config or web.config